# Создание инсталлятора средствами Setup Wizard и InstallShield

Tags: c#, wpf, installshield

Программа содержит большое количество зависимостей и т.п. Чтобы создать нечто рабочее, при создании инсталлятора добавляла всё из программы, что имело хоть какой-то смысл добавлять.
Дальше произошли странные вещи.
Отправила инсталлятор другу. Он успешно установил программу, проверил её функции, нашел один баг в коде программы. Далее с помощью этого же инсталлятора пытаюсь установить программу на свой компьютер, на компьютер другого знакомого. При попытки включения exe-файла выдается ошибка

[image]

Попробовала создавать инсталлятор по-другому. 12 раз. Средствами Setup Wizard. Убирала лишние файлы, добавляла на всякий случай какие-то из программы. Итог опять эта же ошибка. После 3 попыток сделать инсталлятор силами InstallShield, опять же возникала одна и та же ошибка. Тогда я просто взяла всю папку из bin и отправила её архивом другу и себе. Оба запустили - всё работает, но друг всё-таки перед запуском поймал выше упомянутую ошибку (которая в данном случае никак не повлияла и файл всё-таки запустился). Было замечено, что ошибка появилась в то время, когда exe-шник проверялся антивирусом(Avast в данном случае). И после того, как проверка была пройдена, всё запускалось хорошо.

Суть проблемы такова: на некоторых ПК программа не запускается и выдается ошибка, а на некоторых запуск проходит хорошо после проверки антивирусом файла.
Код на котором выдается ошибка:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:DesignInControl="clr-namespace:DesignInControl;assembly=Circular" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Interface" x:Class="Interface.MainWindow"
        xmlns:playlist="clr-namespace:Playlist;assembly=Playlist"
        Title="VVK Player" Height="500" Width="350" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="False" Icon="Resources/Pictures/icon.png" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Resources.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <local:SongNumberConverter x:Key="songNumberConverter" />
            <local:DurationConverter x:Key="durationConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            <RowDefinition Height="79" />
            <RowDefinition Height="57" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0" />
            <RowDefinition Height="36" />
            <RowDefinition Height="268*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Name="rectangleDraggable" Width="auto" Fill="#5A5A5A" MouseDown="rectangleDraggable_MouseDown" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Button  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="25" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" Style="{StaticResource ClearButton}" Click="buttonClose_Click" Grid.Row="0"
                 MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave" Cursor="Hand">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="Resources/Pictures/no.png" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <Button  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="25" Margin="0,0,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" Style="{StaticResource ClearButton}" Click="buttonCollapse_Click" Grid.Row="0"
                 MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave" Cursor="Hand">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="Resources/Pictures/collapse.png" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <Grid Background="#E1E1E1" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Grid Width="325"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBox Name="textboxSongName" Background="#E1E1E1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" Margin="0,20,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" BorderBrush="Transparent" Grid.Row="1" IsEnabled="False"/>
            <TextBox Name="textboxSongTime" Background="#E1E1E1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" Margin="0,40,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" BorderBrush="Transparent" Grid.Row="1" IsEnabled="False"/>
            <Button  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="25" Margin="0,12,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" Style="{StaticResource ClearButton}" Click="buttonMenu_Click" Grid.Row="1"
                     MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave" Cursor="Hand">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Name="MenuButtonImage" Source="Resources/Pictures/menu.png"  />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="25" Margin="0,40,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" Style="{StaticResource ClearButton}" Click="buttonSettings_Click" Grid.Row="1"
                    MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave" Cursor="Hand">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Name="imageSettings" Source="Resources/Pictures/settings.png" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button Height="35" Margin="-1,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource ClearButton}" Click="buttonDownload_Click"
                    MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave" Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="35">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Name="imageDownloadOne" Source="Resources/Pictures/download.png" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Background="#F5F5F5" Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid Margin="20,0" HorizontalAlignment ="Center" Grid.Row="2">
                <Grid Height="8" Margin="8,5,4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="2" MouseUp="rectangleProgressBarMain_MouseUp">
                    <Rectangle Name="rectangleProgressBarMain" Height="8" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="#F59184" HorizontalAlignment="Center" RadiusX="5"
                   RadiusY="5" Width="298" Cursor="Hand"/>
                    <Rectangle Cursor="Hand" Name="rectangleProgressBarElapsed" Height="4" Margin="2,0,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="#F8F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="0" RadiusX="2"
                   RadiusY="2"/>
                    <Ellipse Name="circleProgressBar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Hidden" Fill="#F8F4F5" Width="8" Height="8" Stroke="#F59184" StrokeThickness="1" Cursor="Hand"/>
                </Grid>
                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="35" Margin="-180,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="35" Style="{StaticResource ClearButton}" Click="buttonPrev_Click" Grid.Row="2"
                        MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave" Cursor="Hand">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Name="imagePrev" Source="Resources/Pictures/prev.png" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="35" Margin="-90,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="35" Style="{StaticResource ClearButton}" Click="buttonPause_Click" Grid.Row="2"
                        MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave" Cursor="Hand">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Name="imagePause" Source="Resources/Pictures/pause.png" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="35" Margin="0,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="35" Style="{StaticResource ClearButton}" Click="buttonPlay_Click" Grid.Row="2"
                        MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave" Cursor="Hand">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Name="imagePlay" Source="Resources/Pictures/play.png" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="35" Margin="90,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="35" Style="{StaticResource ClearButton}" Click="buttonStop_Click" Grid.Row="2"
                        MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave" Cursor="Hand">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Name="imageStop" Source="Resources/Pictures/stop.png" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="35" Margin="180,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="35" Style="{StaticResource ClearButton}" Click="buttonNext_Click" Grid.Row="2"
                        MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave" Cursor="Hand">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Name="imageNext" Source="Resources/Pictures/next.png" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Background="#5A5A5A" Grid.Row="4"/>
        <Grid Width="325"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="4">
            <Button x:Name="buttonDownload" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Margin="-1,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="35" Style="{StaticResource ClearButton}" Click="buttonDownload_Click" Grid.Row="4"
                    MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave" Cursor="Hand">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Name="imageDownload" Source="Resources/Pictures/download.png" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <TextBox Name="textboxSearch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="55,9,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="6,0,0,0" Text="Search" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="150" GotFocus="textboxSearch_GotFocus" LostFocus="textboxSearch_LostFocus" TextChanged="textboxSearch_TextChanged" Grid.Row="4" KeyDown="textboxSearch_KeyDown"/>
            <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="5" Height="28"  Width="155" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="4" BorderBrush="#5A5A5A" Margin="51,6,0,0"/>
            <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="185,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="#5A5A5A" Width="30" Height="30" Grid.Row="4"/>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Margin="180,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="35" Style="{StaticResource ClearButton}" Click="buttonSearch_Click" Grid.Row="4"
                    MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave" Cursor="Hand">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Name="imageSearch" Source="Resources/Pictures/search.png" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Margin="220,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="35" Style="{StaticResource ClearButton}" Click="buttonRepeat_Click" Grid.Row="4"
                    MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave" Cursor="Hand">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Name="imageRepeat" Source="Resources/Pictures/repeat_grey.png"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Margin="255,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="35" Style="{StaticResource ClearButton}" Click="buttonMix_Click" Grid.Row="4"
                    MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave" Cursor="Hand">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Name="imageMix" Source="Resources/Pictures/mix.png" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Margin="290,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="35" Style="{StaticResource ClearButton}" Click="buttonSort_Click" Grid.Row="4"
                    MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave" Cursor="Hand">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Name="imageSort" Source="Resources/Pictures/sort.png" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
        <playlist:Playlist Name="listboxPlaylist" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinHeight="268" Height="auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" MinWidth="325" Width="auto" Grid.Row="5" 
                           ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" MouseDoubleClick="listboxPlaylist_MouseDoubleClick" AllowDrop="True">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="0, 0, 0, 1" BorderBrush="{Binding Path=BorderBrush}" Padding="5,5,5,5">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Grid Margin="0,0,10,0">
                                <DesignInControl:CircularProgressBar Name ="progressBar" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Percentage="{Binding Path=Percentage}" SegmentColor="#F59184" StrokeThickness="2" Radius="9"/>
                                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="25" Tag="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource ClearButton}" Click="buttonOk_Click"
                                        MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave" Cursor="Hand">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplatedParent.(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), Converter={StaticResource songNumberConverter}}"/>
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="."/>
                            <TextBlock Padding="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="215" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}" ToolTip="{Binding}"/>
                            <TextBlock Padding="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Duration, Converter={StaticResource durationConverter}}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </playlist:Playlist>
        <ListBox Name="listboxMenu" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,19,38,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" Visibility="Hidden" PreviewMouseUp="listboxMenu_PreviewMouseUp" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListBoxItem>New Login</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Login as...</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
        <ListBox Name="listboxLoginAs" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,15,147,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" Visibility="Hidden" PreviewMouseUp="listboxLoginAs_PreviewMouseUp" MouseLeave="listboxLoginAs_MouseLeave" Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        </ListBox>
        <ListBox Name="listboxSort" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,38,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" Visibility="Hidden" PreviewMouseUp="listboxSort_PreviewMouseUp" Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <ListBoxItem>By downloaded</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>By duration</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>By artist</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>By song title</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
        <Grid Background="#5A5A5A" Grid.Row="6" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></Grid>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

GitHub: [Код на GitHub](https://github.com/LeagueOfDevelopers/VVKMusic)

> Stack trace:
>
> System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, >IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object >rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)    в >System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean >skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)    в System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)    в System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)    в System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)    в System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()    в System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(Object unused)    в System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    в System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)  в System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()    в System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)    в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    в MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    в System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()    в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()    в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    в MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    в MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)    в System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    в System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)  в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    в MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)    в MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)    в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)    в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)   в System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)    в System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)    в System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)    в Interface.App.Main()

Comment: Добавьте в программу [обработчик необработанных исключений](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) и залогируйте точный stack trace. Без этого получается гадание на кофейной гуще.